# Can the number of nodes in a launch file occur issues?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Half of the time I launch my project an issue occurs. I'm wondering if it's simply coming from the fact that I launch 15 nodes with one launch file ? (but I would be surprise that a launch file couldn't handle it)

To be more specific, the issue is only with rviz and/or gazebo failing to launch. Is it because I launch too much nodes at the same time or because I launch all the nodes in the same launch file, causing the needed nodes for Gazebo/rviz not being initialized fast enough ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286900/can-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-launch-file-occur-issues-?/) by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-28**:
What issues come up?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
When Rviz crashes there is no error output but the rviz icon is frozen and I can only execute `killall rviz` to stop it and when Gazebo crashes I have `[gazebo-3] process has died [pid 24958, exit code 255`.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
I asked the question out of desperation, it's probably what @Stefan Kohlbrecher said but I can't find the right soltuion so I try to explore every possibility.

I will post my solution if I manage to solve it since lots of people struggle with Gazebo but no one as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this should not be an issue, we've been using single launch files with a significantly higher number of nodes started with them with no issues.

If rviz and/or gazebo specifically have issues, that might point to a graphics driver related cause (seeing how they both use OGRE and are somewhat sensitive to gfx driver setup). You'll find many posts on this site for both [gazebo graphics crashes](https://www.google.com/search?q=gazebo+graphics+crashes+site:answers.ros.org) and [rviz graphics crashes](https://www.google.com/search?q=rviz+graphics+crashes+site:answers.ros.org).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
Thank you for your answer I've always been wondering about this, and yes you're probably right for the drivers but I already searched a lot without finding the solution.